# Filter a list by hash

Tags: redis

I would like to store a list of items, filter the items, then move through the results by range.

How would I modify the following query to only return items where display=true?

```
HSET item1 display true
HSET item2 display false
HSET item3 display true

LPUSH items item1
LPUSH items item2
LPUSH items item3

LRANGE items 0 3
-- returns [item3, item2, item1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're interested in is expressing a Boolean attribute, just use regular Sets. Adding items is with `SADD items:display item1 item3` and getting them back is trivial with `SMEMBERS`.

**Note 1:** you need to mind the complexity of any Redis command, and especially so when your N is large (more set members, longer lists...). `SMEMBERS` can run for a long time in case your set is large so you should consider using the more polite `SSCAN` variant.

**Note 2:** Sets (and Sorted Sets) are really useful if you're also looking to do set operations (e.g. union, intersect).

**Note 3:** Sorted Sets are a super set of regular Sets (:)) so of course you could use them for the same effect but keeping a score that's either 0 or 1 is a little wasteful IMO.

**Note 4:** another possible direction for you to explore is the use of bitmaps for storing Boolean values - Redis offers a lot of horsepower in that domain.

Let me know if you need more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Redis doesn't really have a way to get from a list based on hash values. But you can get close by using a sorted set. Instead of storing true/false treat true as 1 and false as 0. Then add your elements to a sorted set.

```
zadd items 1 item1
zadd items 0 item2
zadd items 1 item3
```

Now to get items where display==1(true)

```
zrangebyscore items 1 1
```

It will return [item1, item3]

Comment: A viable but slightly wasteful solution IMO - see note 3 in my answer.